# Unit testing with mongodb repositories

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, unit-testing, spring-data-mongodb

I have built application that uses MongoDB and I have came across problem with testing.

As long as I used JPA and some relational database I used some test layer which switched persistence to in-memory database (linke HSQLDB or MySQL) for test purposes. This way I was able to limit IO operations and speed up tests.
However with MongoDB and Spring Data it is very convenient to use repositories based on interfaces extending MongoRepository.

My question is how to deal with unit testing and functional testing when using repositories? For example I have simple class that is anotated as mongo document:

```
public class Company {

@Id
private String id;
@NotEmpty
private String name;
private String description;
private String website;
private String logo;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}    
}
```

and related repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, Serializable> {
}
```

It is used in coresponding controller:

```
@RestController
public class CompanyController {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompanyController.class);
@Autowired
private CompanyRepository repository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/company", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@Valid @RequestBody(required = true) Company company) {
    repository.save(company);
}
}
```

Finally I made two tests (however it could be one covering both tasks) that covers controller api and data format (where I mock repository to prevent from IO operations, and it works nice), and second where I want to make sure that passed object was persisted successfuly. As it cames out it is not so simple. First of all (correct me if I'm wrong) there is no in-memory mongo implementation. Secondly, I cannot verify with mockito execution of save method because of inheritance I suppose.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CompanyControllerNGTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

@Mock
private CompanyRepository repositoryMock;
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
private CompanyController controller;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@DataProvider
public static Object[][] companyJsonProvider() {
    return new Object[][]{
        {Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("name", "JakasFirma")
            .add("description", "jakas firma opis")
            .add("website", "www.jakasfirma.com")
            .add("logo", "jakies logo")
            .build(), status().isOk()},
        {Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("name", "JakasFirma")
            .build(), status().isOk()},
        {Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("description", "jakas firma opis")
            .add("website", "www.jakasfirma.com")
            .add("logo", "jakies logo")
            .build(), status().isBadRequest()},
        {Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .build(), status().isBadRequest()},
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "companyJsonProvider", enabled = false)
public void apiTest(JsonObject companyJson, ResultMatcher expectedStatus) throws Exception {
    //given
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    String content = companyJson.toString();

    //when
    mockMvc.perform(post("/company").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(content)).
            //then
            andExpect(expectedStatus);

}

@Test
public void shouldCreate() throws Exception {
    //given

    //when
    controller.create(mock(Company.class));

    //then
    //verify(repositoryMock, times(1)).save(any(Iterable.class));
}
}
```

I thought about introducing a dao layer between controller and repository that could be mocked and verified bot it adds more complexity and force to encapsulate each method used by repository. Also it doesn't fix problem but partially moves it to lower level.
Is there any method or practice that could help to deal with this kind of problem? Or maybe I should use different approach with mongo?

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing I would stub or write an implementation of CompanyRepository and inject that into your controller (you may need to add a Setter method for CompanyRepository).

For Functional or integration testing I would look at using the following

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:my-context-file.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

In the context file I would expect you to configure the beans that are only required for your test to run.

Comment: The point is that how to verify if create method lead to persisting new instance. When using relational database with ORM I just switched db layer to memory and made assertions on test db instance. In case of mongo I cannot made it this way so I thought about mocking (just like you suggested) and test execution of save method. This way it doesn't work either because Mockito cannot deal with CompanyRepository which inherit from MongoRepository (which defines save method). Of course create method of CompanyController is very simple but the same problem exist with much more complex actions.

Comment: I have figured it out. The problem was with varify method: verify(repositoryMock, times(1)).save(any(Iterable.class)); There should be Company.class instead of Iterable.class - I didn't notice that and thought that Mockito cannot verify inherited method... Works perfectlu now.

Comment: Writing a hashmap-based CompanyRepository is what I did and this works great. As all repositories have a similar interface it is quite easy to write an abstract hashmap-based implementation for all repositories. Then the specific repositories subclass the abstract implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. I recommend you **NOT** to use `MongoRepository` to access to MongoDB for several reasons:

- It is used for easy queries, like findByxxx or findOneByxxxAndyyy. If you want more complex query, even **@Query** cannot give you what you want.
- It is easy to make syntax mistake, because all query conditions are defined by interface.
- Cannot define dynamic queries, like search depending on context, fields, aggregations, etc...

Instead, I recommend you to use **MongoOperations**. It accepts dynamic query with simple/complex criteria, very easy syntax to write your query, etc... For mocking, use Fongo framework, so it is 100% in memory database, so you can do all CRUD operations for asserts...

More info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html

How to mock
https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo#usage-details

**UPDATE:**
If you still need to mock MongoDB repository, use this xml definition:

**mongo-config.xml**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang  http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

    <bean name="fongo" class="com.github.fakemongo.Fongo">
        <constructor-arg value="InMemoryMongo" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongo" factory-bean="fongo" factory-method="getMongo" />

    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="mongo" />

    <!-- localhost settings for mongo -->
    <!--<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" /> -->

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Base package to scan the mongo repositories -->
    <!-- Set your CompanyRepository package -->
    <mongo:repositories base-package="package.to.repositories"  />

</beans>
```

Define your test class by this way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/mongo-config.xml"})
public class CompanyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Resource
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        // Define test logic
    }

}
```